# Why is my custom CQ5 template not showing up?

Tags: templates, components, aem

I'm working with Adobe's CQ version 5.6 . I need to set up a new template for the homepage  new project. After creating the homepage component (i've set my Super Resource type to foundation/components/page) and the template (set the resource type to  Test/components/page/homepage) I open up my siteadmin. When i try to create a new page, my newly created template is nowhere to be found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check Check http://wem.help.adobe.com/content/enterprise/en_US/10-0/wem/developing/templates.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by a set of properties, you probably need to set one or more of these:

- cq:allowedTemplates
- allowedParents
- allowedPaths
- allowedChildren

See [Template Availability in the docs](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/templates.html#Template%20Availability) for more info on the resolution process for what templates are available.

Comment: thanks.. i did correctly set the properties you mentioned, but to no avail.

there is a workaround which I kinda stumbled upon.. I had initially used CRXDE 1.0.1 to develop my template. however, on removing my template, and creating the EXACT same template using CRXDE Lite (the web based IDE) and keeping my properties unchanged, I was able to find my template when I wanted to created a new page..

weird huh?

Comment: @bongman1612 sounds odd to me, but I can't speak to that as I don't use CRXDE at all, and only use CRXDE Lite when I need a quick fix.  I pretty much do all my dev in IntelliJ and use maven build scripts + http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7328 to sync data to/from CRX.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set allowedPaths property "/content(/.*)?" in the template. please visit http://www.cqtuts.com/cq5/what-is-cq5-template.html to learn more.

Comment: Is not the allowedPaths deprecated? And does that not mean it will cause it show up everywhere for potentially every site